# How to select last child element in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How to select last child element in jQuery?

Just the last child, not its descendants.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

You can also do this:

```
<ul id="example">
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li>Third</li>
    <li>Fourth</li>
</ul>

// possibility 1
$('#example li:last').val();
// possibility 2
$('#example').children().last()
// possibility 3
$('#example li:last-child').val();
```

[:last](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/)

[.children().last()](http://api.jquery.com/last/)

[:last-child](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/)

Comment: I don't think `children().last()` and `:last-child` is equal. In this example - yes, but imagine that you have two lists (class="example") and then try to select last elements from both lists...

Comment: @alekwisnia see my example below.

Comment: which way is the fastest?

Comment: @Vic I can't give you the exact answer but options 3 would be the logical. Because option 2 is jumping twice into the DOM by using `children()`. Option 1 is doing it once, but has a custom/jQuery pseudo selector `:last` and  `:last-child` been here pretty long already, does it seem to me that would be the fastest and takes less calculation time to achieve the result.

Comment: `$('#example').children().last()` working fine for me

Answer (score 64):

For perfomance:

```
$('#example').children().last()
```

or if you want a last children with a certain class as commented above.

```
$('#example').children('.test').last()
```

or a specific child element with a specific class

```
$('#example').children('li.test').last()
```

Answer (score 8):

By using the [:last-child selector](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/)?

Do you have a specific scenario in mind you need assistance with?

Answer (score 3):

For 2019 ...

> jQuery 3.4.0 is deprecating :first, :last, :eq, :even, :odd, :lt, :gt,
>   and :nth. When we remove Sizzle, we’ll replace it with a small wrapper
>   around querySelectorAll, and it would be almost impossible to
>   reimplement these selectors without a larger selector engine.
>
> We think this trade-off is worth it. Keep in mind we will still support the positional methods, such as .first, .last, and .eq. Anything you can do with positional selectors, you can do with positional methods instead. They perform better anyway.

https://blog.jquery.com/2019/04/10/jquery-3-4-0-released/

So you should be now be using `.first()`, `.last()` instead (or no jQuery).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to select the last child and need to be specific on the element type you can use the selector [last-of-type](https://api.jquery.com/last-of-type-selector/)

Here is an example:

```
$("div p:last-of-type").css("border", "3px solid red");
$("div span:last-of-type").css("border", "3px solid red");

<div id="example">
            <p>This is paragraph 1</p>
            <p>This is paragraph 2</p>
            <span>This is paragraph 3</span>
            <span>This is paragraph 4</span>
            <p>This is paragraph 5</p>
        </div>
```

In the example above both Paragraph 4 and Paragraph 5 will have a red border since Paragraph 5 is the last element of "p" type in the div and Paragraph 4 is the last "span" in the div.

Answer (score 1):

Hi all Please try this property

```
$( "p span" ).last().addClass( "highlight" );
```

Thanks