# jQuery select last span from h1

Tags: jquery

How can I select last span from h1 element?

```
<h1>
    <a href="#">
        <span>Stackoverflow</span>
        <span>This is the text what I want to hide</span>
        <img src="gif.gif">
    </a>
</h1>
```

What I have tried, but not working:

```
$("h1").each(function() {
    $(this).last("span").hide();  
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a single selector: `$("h1 span:last").hide();` This removes the last `span` from the last `h1` on the page. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zRrVE/.
However, if you have multiple `<h1>` elements that you wish to remove `span:last` from, you will have to use jQuery's `.each()` function like this:

```
$("h1").each(function() {
    $(this).find("span:last").hide();  
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zRrVE/2/

Comment: You could also use the last-of-type selector. See my example http://stackoverflow.com/a/42537416/2512022

Comment: @ScottyG That wasn't reliable nearly 4 years ago when this answer was posted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use just one line

```
$("h1 span:last").hide();
```

or

```
$("h1").find("span:last").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

`$("h1").each(function() {
    $(this).find("span:last").hide();

});`