# Why doesn't the ":last-child" selector apply when <body> is the parent?

Tags: html, jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

I have this simple HTML:

```
<body>
  <a>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
  </a>
</body>
```

The divs are children of `<a>`.

From [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/):

> `:last-child Selector` — Selects all elements that are the last child
> of their parent.

However, when [running this code in JSBin:](http://jsbin.com/kamepu/2/edit)

```
 $("div:last-child" ).css('background-color','red')
```

It yields this rendered output:

[image]

Even if we remove `<a>` so that `divs` will be direct children of `<body>`:

```
<body>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
</body>
```

The result is that *nothing* is painted: (http://jsbin.com/kamepu/4)

Those `divs` are children of `<body>`, so why isn't it working?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612794/how-to-select-last-child-element-in-jquery

Comment: @Smile0ff Does it answer my *question* ? (BODY pov)

Comment: Royi: it works me fine, in Chrome, can it be dependent on browser (and version)? http://jsfiddle.net/gg4mpsx3/

Comment: @panther wtf ? could it be jsbin problem ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: sure, it could :-) It should work correctly.

Comment: @panther nope , look here  , same jsfiddle, : http://jsfiddle.net/gg4mpsx3/2/

Comment: Doesn't (interestingly enough) work in Stack Snippets either (`$('div:last-child')`, `$('body div:last-child')` and `$('body :last-child')` all return a `length` of `0`).

Comment: @RoyiNamir: it's in linking scripts, it depends if you link them in `<head>`, before `</body>` or after `</body>`.

Comment: @David Thomas: `body :last-child` should have a nonzero length - the script is always inserted even if the body is marked up empty.

Comment: @BoltClock: true; I was using the given selectors with the `.css('color','red')` method-call from the original question. As `<script>` elements are not rendered the `color` wasn't (obviously) updated, though had I thought to use `css({'color':'red','display':'block'})` it would have been visible/visibly-successful. My own silly fault for not thinking rationally. :-/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you look at the DOM, JS Bin inserts some `script` elements before the closing `</body>` tag, which prevents any of the `div`s from matching `div:last-child`. Remember that although `script` elements are (usually) not rendered, they do exist in the DOM just like any other HTML element, and as a result will affect selector matching.

The last `div` is in fact the last of its type, even if it isn't the very last child of `body`; you can verify this by switching to `:last-of-type` and it will match.

As mentioned in the comments, Stack Snippets does this as well:

```css
div:last-child { text-decoration: underline; }
div:last-of-type { color: red; }
```

```html
<body>
  <div>Red but no underline</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes that's the answer :-). dam* those online tools

Comment: With `div:last-child` you select the `<div>` *that is* (and only *if it is*) the `:last-child` of its parent element.

Comment: @nicael `last-child` and `last-of-type` are different things.

Comment: @Nit confusing things :)

Comment: Well, you were a minute faster. Enjoy hitting your rep-cap that much sooner...sigh. Also: welcome back! It's been odd, having CSS, HTML and JavaScript questions lying around not being answered authoritatively this past couple of months...

Comment: @David Thomas: Thanks! I was wondering if we were gonna bump into each other today. I figured answering a question or two would make it very certain. It's good to be back, although how active I'll be now that I am remains to be seen.

Comment: Yeah, I'm predictably present most days (especially weekends); today is, I think, my 2000th-day anniversary. So, y'know, cupcakes all round! Also, espresso. :)

Answer (score 2):

`:last-child` returs true is the very last child is of this type (`div` in this case).

JSBin links `script`s at the bottom of the page (before `</body>`), so `:last-child` can works with `script` element only.

Solution is to move scripts into `head` section using `document.ready` or after `</body>`.