# How to target a specific tag and add a class in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to tell JQuery to find the section with the class of 'listings', then find the class 'result'. Then add a new class of 'last' to this very last li only.

```
<section class="listings">
   <div class="ignore-this-div">
       <div class="ignore-this-div-as-well">
           <ul>
               <li class="result"></li>
               <li class="result"></li>
           </ul>
       </div>
   </div>
</section>

$(document).ready(function()
    $('listings .result').last.addClass('last')
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select last child element in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612794/how-to-select-last-child-element-in-jquery)

Answer (score 3):

You have invalid last function, should be [`.last()`](https://api.jquery.com/last/) and the `listings` classname selector should have `.` like following :

```
$('.listings .result').last().addClass('last');
```

or you can use [`:last`](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) :

```
$('.listings .result:last').addClass('last');
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, could do it like this:

```
$('.listings .result:last-child').addClass('last')
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1e0ysd1d/

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues with your syntax, this would work:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.listings ul li').last().addClass('last');
});
```

```css
.last{
background-color:#ccc;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="listings">
   <div class="ignore-this-div">
       <div class="ignore-this-div-as-well">
           <ul>
               <li class="result">first</li>
               <li class="result">last</li>
           </ul>
       </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing bracket after `$(document).ready(function()`, `last` is a method and should look like `last()`, you'll also have to put semicolon after `$('listings .result').last().addClass('last')`

Your jQuery should look like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.listings ul li').last().addClass('last');
});
```