# How to check if last child in a div is <img> with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Assume I have a div that is dynamically populated by input entered by user.
How do you check if the last child in a `div` is a `<img>`. The html code below gives an idea of what I'm trying to achieve.

```
<div>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <!-- Check if this is img element -->
    <img src='example.jpg' > 
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the last child of an element you use [How to select last child element in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612794):

```
$('div').children().last()
```

To test if an element is an `img` you use [`.is('img')`](http://api.jquery.com/is/).

Then you combine them to `$('div').children().last().is('img')`

Or you can use the [`parent > child`](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) selector in combination with `:last-child`

```
$("div > img:last-child").length > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="myKey">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <img src='example.jpg' > /* Check if this is img element*/
</div>
```

and code:

```
var lastChild = jQuery("#myKey").children().last();
var isImg = lastChild.is("img"); //true or false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`:last-child`](https://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/) selector and get `length` of selector or use [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method like bottom code

```
if ($("div > img:last-child").length > 0) 
// Or
if ($("div > img").is(":last-child"))
```

```js
if ($("div img").is(":last-child"))
    console.log("last child is img");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <img src='example.jpg' >
</div>
```

Comment: This will also have `length > 0` for `<p>Some text<img src='example.jpg' ></p><p>Some text</p>`, so it probably is not the best solution.

Comment: For this simple example it will work. But if the OP plans to use that in a more complex code it **might** fail because it does not check if `img` is the last child of `div`, but it checks if there is on `img` descendant (not child)  that is the last child of its parent [see this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p91nk35u/).

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick:

```
$( "div img:last-child" )
```

Comment: You use an `ancestor descendant` selector so it will also find `<p>Some text<img src='example.jpg' ></p><p>Some text</p>`, which probably is not what the OP is looking for. So it might be better to use `$( "div > img:last-child" )`

Answer (score -1):

```js
var last = $('div').children().last();
if ( last.is( "img" ) ) {
    alert("image");
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <img src='example.jpg' > /* Check if this is img element*/
</div>
```