# How to find last child of child?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```html
<div class="group-box">
  <p>test1</p>
  <div class="group-box">
    <p>test2</p>
    <div class="group-box">
      <p>test3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

i want to get **last** $('.group-box')
how to find this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
var last  = $(".group-box:last");
```

you will get the last child

and checkout these answers

[How to select last child element in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612794/how-to-select-last-child-element-in-jquery)

[select deepest child in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787924/select-deepest-child-in-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

```js
alert($('.group-box:last').text())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="group-box">
  <p>test1</p>
  <div class="group-box">
    <p>test2</p>
    <div class="group-box">
      <p>test3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$( ".group-box:last-child" )
```

selector for last child/element

Comment: Your missing the `.`

Comment: This is a wrong selector and obviously not a good answer.

Comment: yes,,missed it by mistake,, class selector.. thanks,