# How to find the first element with specific class from html file using ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I have html file that contains code like :

```
<ol class='items'>

    <li class='item'>
        <div class='content'>
            <p class='title'>
                Item Title
            </p>
            <div class="text">
                Item Description
            </div>
            <div class="itemImg">
                <img src='Image src' />
             </div>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li class='item'>
        <div class='content'>
            <p class='title'>
                Item Title
            </p>
            <div class="text">
                Item Description
            </div>

        </div>
    </li>

    ....

</ol>
```

The JQuery:

```
var file = 'index.html';
$.get(
    file,
    function (data) {
        const html = $(data),
              item = html.find('li.item'),
              title = item.find('p.title'),     
              text = item.find('div.text'),               
              img = item.find('div.itemImg');

        $('.fetchedItem').html(item[0]);              
        $('.fetchedimg').html(img[0]);

        if(img[0]){
            //Do Something
        }     
    }
);
```

I want to get the last `li` with class `item` , Also for the if statement , Sometimes there is a `div` with class `itemImg` and sometimes not , So I want to check if this `div` exist in the first `li` with class `item` or not.

Comment: `li.itemImg:last`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select last child element in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612794/how-to-select-last-child-element-in-jquery)

Comment: `if ($('div.itemImg')){ /*exists*/}`

Comment: Hi - just following up. Was your question answered satisfactorily? If there is more we can help with, please add a comment below an answer, or edit your question to clarify what else you need help with. Otherwise, it would be great if you could choose a "best answer" (by clicking the checkmark beside the answer) to close out the question. **If no answer provided helpful information, please add your own answer and select that as the best answer. You won't get any points for doing so, but that will close out the question.** *Thanks!*

Answer (score 0):

You can use ':last' and ':first' to target the first/last divs with class "item".

Note that I use `lastItem[0]` -- this is because the code `$('li.item:last')` returns a jQuery ***object***, and to get the actual element you need to use `[0]`

```js
$('#myButt').click(function(){
    //Get last div with class "item"
    var lastItem = $('li.item:last');
    alert(lastItem[0].id);
    
    //Does a div exist under 1st .item with class .itemImg
    if ($('li.item:first').find('.itemImg').length) alert('Yes it exists');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class='items'>

    <li id="li_1" class='item'>
        <div class='content'>
            <p class='title'>
                Item Title
            </p>
            <div class="text">
                Item Description
            </div>
            <div class="itemImg">
                <img src='Image src' />
             </div>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li id="li_2" class='item'>
        <div class='content'>
            <p class='title'>
                Item Title
            </p>
            <div class="text">
                Item Description
            </div>

        </div>
    </li>

 
    <li id="li_3" class='item'>
        <div class='content'>
            <p class='title'>
                Item Title
            </p>
            <div class="text">
                Item Description
            </div>

        </div>
    </li>
   <button id="myButt">CLick Me</button>

</ol>
```